# Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults. Failure on top of Dts.Events.FireError() is good?

Tags: c#, ssis

In the script task:

```
else if (val == 0)
{    
    Dts.Events.FireError(0, "", "Custom Message ", "", 0);
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
```

When we have `Dts.Events.FireError()` in the script task, and when it gets invoked  it fails the task as well as displaying the custom error message. So is is good to write the

```
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
```

to fail the task as in the above code.
Is it not like calling the fail twice?
Any use case we should have this both.

Answer (score 1):

### Should we use both

"It depends." How do you want to handle error handling?

My experience has been that it is cleaner to set the TaskResult to Failure and then use precedence constraints out of the task to drive control flow behavior. That is, "yes, this task failed but this package still has work to do." e.g. The file we expected isn't there - that's the error, but I'm going to take an error path to drive the next action (send email alert about missing file)

Otherwise, you get to use the Event Handlers which is totally a valid approach but for all the shops I've consulted in, maybe *two* have used them well. Many people get tripped up over the possibility that an event is raised several times due to container nesting and reraising of events.

If I know I am killing out execution from a Task, then FireError event can be helpful as it helps me log exactly why I'm aborting processing (File not found exception).

Comment: Thanks BillinKC, there was already Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure in my script task, but not the error mssage, hence looking to add the Dts.Events.FireError(0, "", "Custom Message ", "", 0);  But if we add the events handler, i am thinking to remove the Failure. Hence should i keep both or get rid of the Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure; is my confusion.

Comment: I'm a fan of being explicit with my intentions so I would keep the assignment of the TaskResult = failure in there even though the firing of the error will result in the same